# How to test React Native Button's simulate?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I trying to test some components, and I would like to spy after an onPress but for some reason its not being called:

```
it('expect press', () => {
    const listItem = wrapper.find('ListItem')
    listItem.simulate('onPress')
    console.log(mockFn.mock)
})
```

When I debugging the component, I can clearly see that I selected the right element, but yet the simulate do not happen :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
listItem.simulate('Press')
```